# Can 3 level 20 PCs take on Baphomet?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, encounter-design

For future ideas, I was just wondering if a party of 3 level 20 PCs could take down Baphomet? This would be a 5e campaign using his stats from a published adventure (spoilered below).

> Out of the Abyss

Comment: Can you clarify what part of running/simulating the battle yourself to find out if they could gave you trouble?

Comment: What resources do the party have? What composition? Are you interested in the CR calculation or general opinion of if it is possible?

Comment: Do you have any idea what classes your characters will be playing?

Comment: For reference, Baphomet's statblock and info is on p. 234-235 of the adventure, in Appendix D. He is listed as a CR23 creature.

Comment: CR 22 is considered the start of "Deadly" for 3 lvl20... but that can swing wildly depending on what the composition is and what the characters have at their disposal. So we will need more information to help you.

Comment: If you have 3 players and want them to try to play through an adventure involving Baphomet but have yet to design their characters, you should say that in your question too (and whether you will inform them that it will be a very difficult campaign prompting them to optimize their strategy).